# I'm looking for a help for drawing this diagrams

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I'm looking for a help for drawing this diagrams:

[image: Some commutative diagram]

[image: Triangle]

Comment: Hi Angel, [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) It's usually best to show what you have attempted first, and then specify in your question where you're struggling. Have a look in the manual, and search for 'commutative diagrams' on this site; that should get you started. Welcome!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/14). On this website we prefer not to have questions of the ["draw it for me"](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1538/14) type. There are plenty of questions here which would help you draw these diagrams. If you are having problems with a specific issue in the graph, then this is the place, but you should provide a code showing your effort in trying to do it. I am voting to close this as too localised but I encourage you to improve this question and try again.

Comment: @Vivi (and others) please allow a bit of time before voting to close- we should welcome new members, and give them time to modify their question :)

Comment: I can not draw second diagram,in fact I don't know how to draw Convex curve shape.

Comment: “On this website we prefer not to have questions of the "draw it for me" type.” -- One would think so but people don't act like it. From what I have seen these questions always get answers, sometimes even really fast. I guess people like to show their TikZ skills...

Comment: @cgnieder This is why I tried to close it fast... But yes, perhaps if people like answering, then we should just let it be?

Comment: @Vivi I agree with you. Imho, people shouldn't be answering (and accordingly, the answers didn't come from very active/tex.sx-experienced users). Meta-question (kind of a pet peeve of mine): [Should we answer really bad questions?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2414)

Comment: @doncherry Not only did they answer, but they received a high number of upvotes really quickly. I am very soft on closing questions especially from newbies, but I have no problems with questions like this being closed immediately (with a nice comment explaining to the OP why the question is being closed). On the other hand, I don't think we can prevent this from happening. Maybe it is not our job to force people to learn and put effort into things. If there are people happy to answer, then so be it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For the second figure, hope the following code helps. I cannot clearly see whether one of the curves is dashed. If that's not the case, remove `[dashed]` in the code.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (o) at (0,2);
\coordinate (a) at (-4,0);
\coordinate (b) at (4,0);
\draw (o) -- (a) -- (b) -- cycle;
 \draw (0,0) arc (-53:53:1.25);
\draw[dashed] (0,2) arc (-53:53:-1.25);
\end{tikzpicture}

 \end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

As for the first figure, you can easily achive with `tikz-cd`.
This is one possibility.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=small]
 \mathcal{X}^*\arrow{rr}{\rho} &  & \mathcal{M}^*\\
 & \frac{\mathcal{X}^*}{\mathcal{M}^\perp} \arrow[swap]{ur}{\tilde{\rho}}\arrow{ul}{Q}&
 \end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

with the following result:[image]

If you want to keep the fonts (almost) in your image,

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=small]
 \mathscr{X}^*\arrow{rr}{\rho} &  & \mathscr{M}^*\\
 & \dfrac{\mathscr{X}^*}{\mathscr{M}^\perp} \arrow[swap]{ur}{\tilde{\rho}}\arrow{ul}{Q}&
 \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 a few folks recommend using `\documentclass{standalone}` for images- it has many advantages, including very-easily cropped pictures :)

Comment: Thanks all and I apologize that my question was not raised properly.I can draw The First commutative diagram by xymatrix.‎\begin{displaymath}‎ ‎\xymatrix{‎ ‎\mathcal{X}‎^* \ar[rr]^{‎\rho‎}& &‎ ‎‎\mathcal{M}‎^* \\‎ ‎& ‎‎‎\frac{\mathcal{X}^*}{\mathcal{M}^‎\bot‎}‎\ar[ru]_{‎\tilde\rho‎} \ar[lu]^{Q} &}‎‎ ‎ ‎\end{displaymath}‎‎

Answer (score 6):

For the first commutative diagram (still it need some fonts improvements):

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes, row sep=3em,
                column sep=2.5em, text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.25ex] {
            \mathcal{X}^* & & \mathcal{M}^* \\
            & \dfrac{\mathcal{X}^*}{\mathcal{M}^{\perp}} & \\ };
            \path[->] (m-1-1) edge node[above] {$\rho$} (m-1-3);
            \path[->] (m-2-2) edge node[below] {$Q$} (m-1-1);
            \path[->] (m-2-2) edge node[below] {$\tilde\rho$} (m-1-3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Resulting image.]